# how to remove custom words from word cloud in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, nlp, word-cloud

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white",width=1600,height=800).generate(' '.join(df1['text'].tolist()))
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10), facecolor='k')
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
```

The word cloud that gets shown has data that I don't think is relevant, such as user, need, anyone, issue, trying, and some other words. I have already removed stop words, but how can I remove a custom list of words from the word cloud? This is a word cloud from data I scraped from slack, and I want it to representative of questions people are asking in the channel that are more related to things like email, server, outlook, duo etc.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

- get the list of the default stopwords
- add your custom stopwords
- convert to a set
- use in WordClould

```py
w = WordCloud()
stop_words = list(w.stopwords)
custom_stop_words = ['user', 'need']
stop_words = set(stop_words + custom_stop_words)

wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white",width=1600,height=800, stopwords=stop_words).generate(' '.join(df1['text'].tolist()))
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10), facecolor='k')
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a list of words you want to remove, I think you can remove them from `df1` before fitting the word cloud.

Comment: Please skip the first paragraph of your answer (... I think... => If in doubt leave it out). There is the stopwords argument for this purpose. Still the second part is a valuable answer to the presented problem.